# Area below probabilities

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Let $p$ be probabilities and $D$ is the real

How can I proof that the areas

$$\int p \; d F_{p}(p|D=1) = \int (1-p) \; d F_{1-p}(1-p|D=1)$$

are equal. Where $F_{p}$ is the empirical distribution function of $p$.

Illustration:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
set.seed(123)
predRisk <- plogis(runif(1000,-1,10))
plot(ecdf(1-predRisk))
plot(ecdf(predRisk))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the change of variable $p=1-q$ (don't forget the Jacobian and the use of the correct integration range). Maybe this should be a comment.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Why not expand this a little--it does seem like a potential answer.